# proof of negative definite for B if A is negative definite (AB=C, C is positive definite)

Tags: linear-algebra

Let AB = C, and C is a positive definite matrix. If A is negative definite, then B is also negative definite. This is true if A, B and C are diagonal matrices. Can it also be true for general case?

Comment: $B$ is not symmetric in general

Comment: Are we assuming that definiteness requires the matrix to be symmetric?

Comment: yes if $AB=BA$, because then $A$ and $B$, and hence $C$, are simultaneously diagonalizable...

Comment: The matrix  $A$ is negative iff $-A$ is positive. So the problem can be reduced to positive definite matrices as $(-A)(-B)=C.$